# Gradient in integral transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, chain-rule, orthogonal-matrices

I have a question on the handling of gradients in coordinate transformations:

For a coordinate transformation in form of a rotation defined by the mapping $\Phi: \Omega \mapsto \Omega'$, $\psi \mapsto R\psi = x$ with an orthogonal matrix R, the following integral transformation can be made:

$\int_{\Omega'} u(x) dx = \int_\Omega u(R\psi) d\psi$,

as |det R| = 1.

Now I am wondering how this integral transformation looks if there is the gradient $\nabla_x u(x)$ on the left, as the derivatives also depend on the coordinate system (therefore the subscript x). I know that due to the chain rule $\nabla_\psi(u(R\psi)) = \nabla_\psi u(R\psi) R$, so my question is if I can just write:

$\int_{\Omega'} \nabla_x  u(x) dx = \int_\Omega R \nabla_\psi u(R\psi) d\psi$

Comment: It seems correct. Using Einstein notation $x^i=R^i\,_ky^k$ and $y^l=(R^{-1})^l\,_ix^i$ (summation over repeating indices). For the rotational matrix $(R^{-1})^l\,_i=(R^T)^l\,_i$ ($R^T$ - transposed matrix). Then $\nabla_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial \,y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}=(R^T)^j\,_i\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$ $$\int_{\Omega_x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} u(x) dx=\int_{\Omega_y} (R^T)^j\,_i\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}  u(Ry)|det R| dy=\int_{\Omega_y} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(R^T)^j\,_i  u(Ry) dy=\int_{\Omega_y} (R\nabla_y)_i  u(Ry) dy$$